# Determine value $T=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(z_{k}+1\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z_1, z_2, ..., z_{n}$ is root of equation:

$$z^{n}+z^{n-1}+...+z+1=0$$

Determine value $T=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(z_{k}+1\right)$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Using [Transformation of equations](http://www.iitjeemathematics.com/conte/quadratic-equations/14-transformation-of-equations) set $z+1=y\implies z=y-1$ which will satisfy the given equation

Now simplify and apply [Vieta's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas#Basic_formulas)

---

Alternatively, we have $\displaystyle \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}=0$ where $z\ne1$

Putting $\displaystyle z=y-1,(y-1)^{n+1}-1=y^{n+1}+\cdots+\underbrace{(-1)^n-1}=0$

$z-1$ corresponds to $y-2$

Applying Vieta's formula, $\displaystyle 2\prod_{r=1}^ny_r=2\prod_{r=1}^n(z_r+1)=(-1)^n-1$