# If $1,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,..,\alpha_{n-1}$ denote the $n^{th}$ roots of unity, then what is $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-\alpha_k)$

Tags: complex-numbers, cyclotomic-polynomials

Here's what we did in class :

$f(z)=z^n-1$ has all of the $n$ $n^{th}$ roots of $1$ as it's zeroes. Let's say that $\alpha_1=e^{\iota(2\pi/n)}$ and $\alpha_j=(\alpha_1)^j$ for $j\in[1,n-1]$. So $1,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...,\alpha_{n-1}$ are the said $n$ roots. This implies that :

$$z^n-1=(z-1)(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)...(z-\alpha_{n-1})$$
$$\implies \dfrac{z^n-1}{z-1}=(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)...(z-\alpha_{n-1})\overset{\text{def}}{=}P_n(z),\text{where }z\neq1$$

And as $\dfrac{z^n-1}{z-1}$ denotes the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric progression with the first term as $1$ and the common ratio as $z$, we can say that $\dfrac{z^n-1}{z-1}=1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1}$, again for $z\neq 1$

From this, it can be said that :

$$P_n(z)=1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1},\text{for }z\neq1~~~~~~~~~~~~~~...(1)$$

What our teacher did next was write $(1-\alpha_1)(1-\alpha_2)...(1-\alpha_{n-1})$ as $P_n(1)$ and equate it to $1+1+1^2+...+1^{n-1}=n$, from relation $(1)$, even though it forbids $z$ being $1$, claiming that $(1)$ was an identity and was applicable to $\Bbb C$.

I'm really confused about this. We derived it with the assumption that $z\neq1$ and I don't see why it shouldn't be taken into account.

Thank you!

Comment: Take the limit.

Comment: And if you do not want to consider limits: your teacher showed that the polynomial $P_n(z):=(z-\alpha_1)\cdots(z-\alpha_{n-1})$ coincides with the other polynomial $Q_n(z):=1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1}$ on $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$. That is more than enough for the two polynomials to be equal. (You would only need $P_n(z)$ and $Q_n(z)$ to coincide at $n$ distinct points.)

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Yeah but the limit won't give the value at precisely $1$, would it?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643689/determine-value-t-prod-k-1n-leftz-k1-right   and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376781/simplification-of-product-of-complex-numbers and

Comment: @nejimban I'm sorry but how's that "more than enough" for the two polynomials to be equal?

Comment: If $P$ and $Q$ are two polynomials of degree at most $n$  and $P(a_i)=Q(a_i)$ for distinct $a_0,\ldots,a_n\in\Bbb C$, then $P\equiv Q$. That comes from the fundamental fact that a polynomial of degree at most $n$ cannot have more than $n$ roots.

Comment: @nejimban Yes but is $P_n$ even a polynomial by definition? It's domain doesn't include $1$, after all.

Comment: I (and I guess your teacher also) defined $P_n(z):=(z-\alpha_1)\cdots(z-\alpha_{n-1})$ for *all* $z\in\Bbb C$. But I agree that $P_n(z)=\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$ for $z\neq1$, of course.

Comment: My teacher didn't explicitly define $P_n(z)$, I just wanted to have a way to not have to write the continued product again and again. My main question is intended to be "We've derived that for $z\neq1$, $(z-\alpha_1)...(z-\alpha_{n-1})=1+z+...+z^{n-1}$, so why's that applicable to $z=1$ as well?" I'm sorry if my language in the question is misleading or something.

Comment: Have you even read my comments? …

Comment: @nejimban uh huh

Comment: We don't care how the two polynomials are called. They are polynomials and you have derived that they coincide for all $z\neq1$. That is enough to conclude.

Comment: I utterly fail to see how. That's basically what my question is. HOW is that enough to conclude so?

Comment: I wrote why like three times? If you prefer, consider the difference of both sides (so $(z-\alpha_1)\cdots(z-\alpha_{n-1})-(1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{n-1})$). It is still a polynomial, and it is equal to $0$ at infinitely many points (for all $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\{1\}$), so it is identically zero (thus zero also at $z=1$).

Comment: @nejimban Ah, I feel stupid now. I see what you're trying to say. Apologies. Well, since it's 2 polynomials, I see how it can be used to derive the product of all of the roots and why it depends on $n$ and stuff too, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

Observe that,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{z\to 1}\frac {z^n-1}{z-1}&=\lim_{z\to 1}P_n(z)\\
&=P_n(z)\mid_{z=1}\\
&=P_n(1).\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you do that? $P_n$ is not defined at 1

Comment: Right, I see how the limit shows that the value of $P_n(1^+)$ and $P_n(1^-)$ is in fact $1$ but that still doesn't change that $P_n(1)$ is undefined, right?

Comment: @nonuser Why can't you define $P_n(z):=(z-\alpha_1)\cdots(z-\alpha_{n-1})$ for $z=1$? It is a polynomial!

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Think about $\frac xx ≠1$, when $x=0$.  But, their limit is equal, at $x=0$, right?

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, but saying $\left.\dfrac xx\right|_{x=0}=1$ is still wrong, right?

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Yes, but our point is the equality of their limits.  Because, note that, I didn't write $\frac {z^n-1}{z-1}\large{\mid}_{z=1}$, right?

Comment: Yep, but I don't think the point should be the equality of the limit. Basically, where  $z\neq1$, we have deduced that $1+z+z^2+...+z^{n-1}=(z-\alpha_1)(z-\alpha_2)...(z-\alpha_{n-1}$, so why is that applicable to $z=1$ as well? I can't see how the limit helps us answer this question :/

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu forget about limits. Both sides of the equation you just wrote are polynomials. They are equal on $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$, so they are equal on $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu $$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac {(x-1)(x-2)}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2}(x-1)=(x-1)\mid_{x=2}.$$ Does this example answer your question?

Comment: @lonestudent I'm afraid not, sorry. I think I understand how limits work well enough, but I don't see how limits answer my question.

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu $\frac{x}{x}$ is not defined at $x=0$ but it's limit is defined

Comment: @lonestudent I honestly don't know, I'm pretty convinced by nejimban's answer now, but I still don't see how limits help. Thank you very much for the help, though!

Comment: @RajdeepSindhu Suppose that, you want to calculate $P(x)=x-1$ at $x=5$. Note that $P(x)=\frac {(x-1)(x-5)}{x-5}$ holds for all $x≠5$. However, $$P(5)=P(x)\mid_{x=5}=\lim_{x\to 5}\frac {(x-1)(x-5)}{x-5}$$, right?

Comment: @nonuser The point is, we say $\frac {z^n-1}{z-1}=P_n(z)$ holds for all $z≠1$. We don't say, $P_n(z)$ is undefined at the point $z=1$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @lonestudent Yep, I get what you mean.